# setting table attributes in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, django-tinymce

When ever I create a table in TinyMCE I get:

```
<table style="width: 200px; ...
```

How can I change this to:

```
<table width="200px" ...
```

I only ask becasue I'm passing the content on to [pisa](http://www.htmltopdf.org/) and it needs all tags to have attributes, not style values. I have set `inline_styles` and `safeHTML` both to false to little avail :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you editor is your tinymce editor object try

```
$(editor.getBody()).find('table').attr('width', '200px');
```

Comment: I could do that but I want TinyMCE to use tab attributes (where applicable) insted of putting them inside the style attribute